# How do I get terminal programs to have a black background instead of a solarized black one?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have my Terminal color scheme set to White on Black. However, whenever I use console programs such as aptitude or minicom, the black background takes on a solarized appearance. I abhor the solarized look. The aptitude program has no color options. The minicom program has limited options, but the background color option clearly says BLACK. Yet, I still get a solarized background.

Answer (score 0):

### `gnome-terminal`

I am not sure if it is possible to override the colour settings of aptitude and minicom, but I suggest that you try with

- the general Settings of Ubuntu - Universal Access - High Contrast [On]
- the Preferences of Gnome Terminal - Colors - Use colors from system theme [Off]

You can also try various colour schemes, if they survive the 'attack' from your problematic programs. For example, try colour scheme 'white on black'.

[image]

### `xterm`

If still problems, you can install and use `xterm`, maybe `xterm -dc` will help keep the black background. Probably you will also prefer to modify the xterm font. so the following alias may be useful

```
alias xterm='xterm -dc -fa default -fs 14'
```

This helps me.

[image]

See `man xterm` for more details.

### If still problems

Let me know if this does not help you - and I will delete the answer.